# Python regex match certain floating point numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match: 0 or more numbers followed by a dot followed by ( (0 or more numbers) but not (if followed by a d,D, or _))

Some examples and what should match/not:

match:

```
['1.0','1.','0.1','.1','1.2345']
```

not match:

```
['1d2','1.2d3','1._dp','1.0_dp','1.123165d0','1.132_dp','1D5','1.2356D6']
```

Currently i have:

```
"([0-9]*\.)([0-9]*(?!(d|D|_)))"
```

Which correctly matches everything in the match list. But for those in the things it should not match it incorrectly matches on:

```
['1.2d3','1.0_dp','1.123165d0','1.132_dp','1.2356D6']
```

and correctly does not match on:

```
['1d2','1._dp','1D5']
```

So it appears i have problem with the ([0-9]*(?!(d|D|_)) part which is trying to not match if there is a d|D|_ after the dot (with zero or more numbers in-between). Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `^\d+[.]\d+$`??

Comment: should it accept `0.23ef`? since this does not have d|D|_?

Comment: I had not tried ^\d+[.]\d+$, which seems to work well. On 0.23ef it should match as there is no d|D|_

Comment: then you should have `\d+[.](?!.*[_Dd]).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a negative lookahead, you might use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any character that is not in the character class.

If you only want to match word characters without the `dD_` or a whitespace char you could use `[^\W_Dd\s]`.

You might also remove the `\W` and `\s` to match all except `dD_`

```
^[0-9]*\.[^\W_Dd\s]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]*\.` Match 0+ times a digit 0-9 followed by a dot
- `[^\W_Dd\s]*` Negated character class, match 0+ times a word character without `_` `D` `d` or whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLLt4B/1)

If you don't want to use anchors to assert the start and the end of the string you could also use lookarounds to assert what is on the left and right is not a non whitspace char:

```
(?<!\S)[0-9]*\.[^\W_Dd\s]*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLLt4B/2)

Comment: this does not capture `1.9e5` for example. Look at what OP wants

Comment: @Onyambu Are you sure OP also wants to match that? I see 4 examples: what should match, what should not match. Then what is matched  (which is wrong) and what is not matched (which is correct). You could be right thought, I am just not sure.

Comment: read my comment. I did ask and and that is the response I got. read the comments above

Comment: @Onyambu Oh my, I missed that one, thanks for pointing it out. Let me update it.

Answer (score 1):

`\d*[.](?!.*[_Dd]).*` is what you are looking for: